# Maximum possible memory usage

Tags: mysql

recently my MYsql CPU usage is 120% and this is the mysqltuner
can you please suggest for me a solution ?

```
    [root@server1 ~]# mysqltuner
 >>  MySQLTuner 1.8.3 - Major Hayden <major@mhtx.net>
 >>  Bug reports, feature requests, and downloads at http://mysqltuner.pl/
 >>  Run with '--help' for additional options and output filtering

[--] Skipped version check for MySQLTuner script
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 10.5.20-MariaDB
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Log file Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err exists
[--] Log file: /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err(58M)
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err is not empty
[!!] Log file /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err is bigger than 32 Mb
[OK] Log file /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err is readable.
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err contains 5671 warning(s).
[!!] /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err contains 8815 error(s).
[--] 77 start(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err
[--] 1) 2023-05-19 22:58:18 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 2) 2023-05-19 20:25:05 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 3) 2023-05-19 18:36:29 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 4) 2023-05-19 18:36:24 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 5) 2023-05-19 18:36:19 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 6) 2023-05-19 18:36:15 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 7) 2023-05-19 18:36:10 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 8) 2023-05-19 18:36:05 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 9) 2023-05-19 18:33:24 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 10) 2023-05-19 18:33:19 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
[--] 76 shutdown(s) detected in /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err
[--] 1) 2023-05-19 22:58:15 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 2) 2023-05-19 20:25:02 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 3) 2023-05-19 18:36:26 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 4) 2023-05-19 18:36:22 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 5) 2023-05-19 18:36:17 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 6) 2023-05-19 18:36:13 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 7) 2023-05-19 18:36:08 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 8) 2023-05-19 18:36:03 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 9) 2023-05-19 18:33:22 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
[--] 10) 2023-05-19 18:33:17 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -----------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +Aria +CSV +InnoDB +MEMORY +MRG_MyISAM +MyISAM +PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA +SEQUENCE
[--] Data in MyISAM tables: 3.7M (Tables: 170)
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 1.7G (Tables: 2673)
[OK] Total fragmented tables: 0

-------- Analysis Performance Metrics --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] innodb_stats_on_metadata: OFF
[OK] No stat updates during querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

-------- Security Recommendations ------------------------------------------------------------------
[OK] There are no anonymous accounts for any database users
[OK] All database users have passwords assigned
[!!] There is no basic password file list!

-------- CVE Security Recommendations --------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Skipped due to --cvefile option undefined

-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 15m 30s (405K q [435.873 qps], 60K conn, TX: 252G, RX: 56M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 82% / 18%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 125.7G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 518.1G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 16.8G global + 1.0G per thread (500 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 0B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 156.2G (124.25% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 518.1G (412.24% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/405K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 27% (139/500)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (1/60771)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 3K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 8
[!!] Temporary tables created on disk: 94% (27K on disk / 29K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (139 created / 60K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 97% (126K hits / 129K requests)
[OK] table_definition_cache(40000) is upper than number of tables(3036)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (370/40K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (3K immediate / 3K locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Performance schema is disabled.
[--] Memory used by P_S: 0B
[--] Sys schema isn't installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 64 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.5.20-MariaDB)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.2% (24M used / 134M cache)
[OK] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 128.0M/560.0K
[OK] Read Key buffer hit rate: 99.8% (1K cached / 3 reads)

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 12.6G/1.7G
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 3.2G * 1/12.6G should be equal to 25%
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 101 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.98% (452129093 hits/ 452197113 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 189.95% (8618 hits/ 4537 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 13155 writes)

-------- Aria Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Aria Storage Engine is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/352.0K
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 95.8% (641K cached / 27K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err is > 32Mb, you should analyze why or implement a rotation log strategy such as logrotate!
    Check warning line(s) in /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err file
    Check error line(s) in /var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err file
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Reduce your overall MySQL memory footprint for system stability
    Dedicate this server to your database for highest performance.
    Configure your accounts with ip or subnets only, then update your configuration with skip-name-resolve=1
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
    Temporary table size is already large - reduce result set size
    Reduce your SELECT DISTINCT queries without LIMIT clauses
    Performance schema should be activated for better diagnostics
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/mysql/mysql-sys for MySQL
    Consider installing Sys schema from https://github.com/FromDual/mariadb-sys for MariaDB
Variables to adjust:
  *** MySQL's maximum memory usage is dangerously high ***
  *** Add RAM before increasing MySQL buffer variables ***
    join_buffer_size (> 4.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
    performance_schema = ON enable PFS
```

and this is my.cnf :

```
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log-error=/var/lib/mysql/nc-ph-3696.arabtimenews.com.err
performance-schema=0
innodb_buffer_pool_size=12928M
max_connections = 500
max_allowed_packet=1024M
open_files_limit=39999
innodb_file_per_table=1
unix_socket=OFF
join_buffer_size=4096
join_buffer_space_limit=4096
optimizer_switch='optimize_join_buffer_size=on'
tmp_table_size=4000M
max_heap_table_size=4000M
max_tmp_tables=300
table_definition_cache=40000
table_open_cache=20000
innodb_log_file_size=3232M
table_open_cache=20000
innodb_log_file_size=3232M
```

Processor Information

```
Total processors: 64
Processor #1
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #2
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #3
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #4
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #5
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #6
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2800.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #7
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #8
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #9
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #10
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #11
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #12
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #13
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #14
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #15
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #16
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #17
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2800.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #18
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2800.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #19
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #20
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #21
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #22
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #23
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #24
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #25
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #26
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #27
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #28
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #29
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #30
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #31
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #32
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #33
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2800.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #34
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #35
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #36
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #37
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #38
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #39
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #40
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #41
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #42
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #43
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #44
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #45
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #46
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #47
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #48
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #49
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #50
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #51
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #52
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #53
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #54
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #55
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2800.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #56
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #57
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #58
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #59
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #60
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #61
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #62
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #63
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
1500.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
Processor #64
Vendor
AuthenticAMD
Name
AMD EPYC 7282 16-Core Processor
Speed
2000.000 MHz
Cache
512 KB
```

Memory Information

```
[    0.000000] Memory: 6621048k/135527424k available (7988k kernel code, 1448416k absent, 2459716k reserved, 5756k data, 2176k init)
```

Current Memory Usage

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      131782472    11295012    58106300      406236    62381160   119457692
Swap:      33554416           0    33554416
Total:    165336888    11295012    91660716
```

Comment: CPU is there to be used.  120% is a little over 1 core. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: thanks for your reply ...

Comment: thanks for your reply ...
the problem that i am trying to solve is this situation : 
i have script that is replying the Facebook comments for all page's posts

Comment: so when the mysql usage is highr than 80%, i saw some errors in replying to some comments  >
EX: page 1 has a post, and this post will have a 3000 comments for 30 minutes 
so the script will answer each post with 3 comment and a private message 
so when the Mysql CPU usage is higher than 80% then the script will answer only 2000 comments and 1000 comments will stay without replying ( my costumers reporting about this problem everyday 
this causing a high cpu usage for

Comment: @Misha Have you applied Rick James's suggestions?  If so, please get a new MySQLTuner posted after 24 hours of uptime and post it without destroying 15minute results you have already posted.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is bogus.  However, here are some things that are set dangerously high:

```
max_connections = 500        -- 200 is probably reasonable
open_files_limit=39999       -- 10000
join_buffer_size=4096        -- 1M   (4096 is too low)
tmp_table_size=4000M         -- 1G
max_heap_table_size=4000M    -- 1G
table_definition_cache=40000 -- 10000
table_open_cache=20000       -- 10000
```

Meanwhile, high CPU implies a poorly indexed or formulated query.  Please provide the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Anyway, "CPU usage is 120%" means that you are using about 1.2 of your 16 cores.  Not a problem.

Comment: @misha It looks like you have 64 processors to me.  If you have applied Rick's Suggestions, after 24 hours of uptime, please post a new MySQLTuner report for review.

Comment: @Misha         What is your situation at this time?  Still need assistance?